# Uncaught jqGrid - No such method: exportToExcel

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, jqgrid

I have a button that it's outside of JQGrid and i'm using jqgrid.min.js v5.2.1

my code is here:

```
$("#export").on("click", function () {
        $("#jqGrid").jqGrid("exportToExcel", {
            includeLabels: true,
            includeGroupHeader: true,
            includeFooter: true,
            fileName: "jqGridExport.xlsx",
            maxlength: 40 // maxlength for visible string data 
        })
    })
```

but when I click on button,I get this error:
Uncaught jqGrid - No such method: exportToExcel

Could you help me how can I solve that? thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error mean that the method is not present, which means that you use version that not support this or you use a custom builder of Guriddo jqGrid JS, where the export module is not included. To check this you can open the Guriddo jqGrid min file and see which modules are included. Search for grid.export.js module.

I recommend you to use the full Guriddo jqGrid version, which can be downloaded [from here](http://www.guriddo.net/downloads/Guriddo_jqGrid_JS_5_2_X_demo.zip)

Comment: Can you please provide a demo which demonstrates the problem?